# In jQuery, to select the nth sibling of a node, is .next() chained n times or .nextAll(':eq(n-1)') faster?

Tags: jquery, siblings

Assuming there are an arbitrary number of siblings of a node, and I wanted to select the `nth sibling` of that node, should I be using `.next()` chained up n times, or should I just use a single call to `.nextAll(':eq(n-1)')`?

Seems like there would be a lot of extra overhead with the former for large n, and possibly a bigger overhead with the latter for large number of siblings. I'm concerned with a case that involves n=2 and a large number of siblings, so I'm not sure if I want to use `.next().next()` or `.nextAll(':eq(1)')`. Does it matter?

Edit: For the case of n=2 and many siblings, it looks like `.next().next()` is fastest according to http://jsperf.com/next-next-vs-nextall-eq-1-vs-nextall-eq-1

Comment: `.nextAll('.bros').eq(4)` for the 5th sibling or `.nextAll()[4]` would work equally well :)

Comment: @thewiglaf: In relation to your last edit. Chaining `next()` is faster when you are looking for the 1st or 5th, 6th item. However, as you chain more and more `next()` calls `.nextAll().eq(?)` becomes progressivley faster. See this example comparing 10 chained `next()` to `eq(10)`. `next()` chaining is now the slowest of the 3 tests!: http://jsperf.com/next-next-vs-nextall-eq-1-vs-nextall-eq-1/2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a few test-cases for you to give you a general idea:

- [**http://jsperf.com/next-vs-nextall-frist/2**](http://jsperf.com/next-vs-nextall-frist/2)
- [**http://jsperf.com/nextall-first-vs-nextuntil-last-next**](http://jsperf.com/nextall-first-vs-nextuntil-last-next)

Also very interesting is the comparing of next() vs getelementbyid:

- [**http://jsperf.com/next-vs-document-getelementbyid/2**](http://jsperf.com/next-vs-document-getelementbyid/2)

You can take any of those test-cases and add your own additional tests.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Turns out .next().next() is fastest for many siblings according to http://jsperf.com/next-next-vs-nextall-eq-1-vs-nextall-eq-1

Comment: @thewiglaf: Be very careful with that. Chaining `next()` is faster when you are looking for the 1st or 5th, 6th item. However, as you chain more and more next calls `.nextAll().eq(?)` becomes progressivley faster. See this example comparing chaining 10 `next()` to each other to `eq(10)`. next chaining is now the slowest of the 3 tests!: http://jsperf.com/next-next-vs-nextall-eq-1-vs-nextall-eq-1/2

Answer (score 4):

What you should do is pay a visit to http://jsperf.com. No need for either worrying or guessing.

Comment: It turns out .next().next() is fastest when there are many siblings. Here is my test: http://jsperf.com/next-next-vs-nextall-eq-1-vs-nextall-eq-1